# How to change pin of thermo sensor?

Tags: firmware, ramps-1.4, anycubic-i3-mega

The thermoresistor on my Anycubic Mega displays nonsense temperatures (e.g. 700 °C), since the resistor in the hotend is working fine the problem is 100 % in the board (Trigorilla RAMPS 1.4). Someone suggested switching the pin of the thermoresistor from `T0` to `T1`, so I soldered it this way. Now I have to cook a personalized firmware for making it work. I opened a custom firmware in VSCode but I do not know what parameter I have to change, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are 2 slots for temperature measurements, you don't need to solder anything, just plug the thermistor from one into the other and switch pins in the firmware. This board is basically a RAMPS 1.4 board, it includes the `pins_RAMPS.h` header file, so in order to switch the T0 with the T1 temperature port, you need to change:

```
//
// Temperature Sensors
//
#ifndef TEMP_0_PIN
  #define TEMP_0_PIN                          13  // Analog Input
#endif
#ifndef TEMP_1_PIN
  #define TEMP_1_PIN                          15  // Analog Input
#endif
```

to:

```
//
// Temperature Sensors
//
#ifndef TEMP_0_PIN
  #define TEMP_0_PIN                          15  // Analog Input
#endif
#ifndef TEMP_1_PIN
  #define TEMP_1_PIN                          13  // Analog Input
#endif
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had to solder the pins since there was no way to insert the cable directly into the board, i do not know how to explain it but f you see he inside of the Anycubic Mega you can understand it immediately. I have edited the firmware and build it but it bricked the printer, i think the board its faulty since previously also the bed heating probe stopped working. Thanks by the way.